# How to properly combine .plist data and CoreData?

Tags: ios, core-data, plist

Let's say I have this class hierarchy:

```
protocol Location {}
class Planet: Location {
}

// That's a spot on some planet
class Site: Location {
   var planet: Planet
}
```

That's what I want to implement.
I want to add planets via a `.plist` file (that's what I think suits best).

Those are pre-added planets that exist in the universe. However, every planet has locations that the user creates. Thus, I need to save these using CoreData.

I'm not sure how to do this. How can I use this class hierarchy that I "hardcoded" in (using `.plist`) alongside `CoreData` models/objects?

For example: How would I create the Site `entity` in CoreData? I can't just add an Attribute `planet` of type `Planet`, that's not possible in CoreData as far as I know.

What's the general approach for this? I hope you understand my problem, it's hard to describe, as this is new to me.

Answer (score 0):

In Core Data create

- Entity `Planet`
- Entity `Site`
- Relationship one-to-many from `Planet` to `Site`

Comment: But the planets aren't saved using CoreData. All "objects" are stored in the `.plist` file. If I created a `Planet` entity, I would need to save all planets to the device's database, right? Or do I mix up something?

Comment: You asked *How would I create the Site entity in CoreData*?  .I'd recommend to use Core Data as main database and the plist file for the initial set of data. Basically you should not use property list and Core Data simultaneously.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I asked. But I also said that the planets aren't using CoreData. Using CoreData as main database sounds like a good solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Get the plist address from your bundle
2. Read the plist contents into an array
3. Iterate through the array, inserting new core data objects as appropriate, populating the properties as defined in the plist
4. Save the context

If any of this seems cryptic to you, you need to dig in further, perhaps by following some tutorials. There are many answers on this platform to every sub-problem of these steps.